# Dealing with political boundaries in grid cell analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, administrative-boundaries, vector-grid, borders

I have point data for Africa and I want to aggregate these data to grid cells which I create by a fishnet. Some grid cells cover parts of 2 or 3 countries. Normally, such cells are by different methods completely assigned to a single country.

I would like to ask whether there is a method to create grid cells that is more sensitive to national borders?

Can I split such cells with country borders and assign them to different countries or is it possible to duplicate such cells and assign them partially to one country?

I use ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to perhaps include a graphic to illustrate what you are trying to describe in words, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best and simplest method is to intersect the fishnet with the countries layer to get parts of cells in the border regions, then aggregate the point data by those partial cells.
[image]